# Liquibase не подлючается к базе данных

Tags: docker-compose, liquibase

Создал локальную базу данных Postrgesql, через докер компосе пишит что не получается подключиться, а если пробывать самим подключиться к дб, через jdbc то все ок

[image: докер компосе]

Unexpected error running Liquibase: Connection could not be created to jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres with driver org.postgresql.Driver.  Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

[image: Заспук через JDBC]